# Xcode for Snow Leopard: where to get

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have an Apple laptop with Snow Leopard (10.6.7) and I need an Xcode with the latest SDK version.
However going to the Apple all I can find is Xcode 4.3 which is for the latest Mac OS X.

Is it possible to find the Xcode version that will work on my version of Mac OS X?

Comment: Or like I mention below maybe there is simply SDK download as I don't really need the whole XCode. But I'm not looking for iOS one I need to do development on the desktop/laptop. BTW is gcc preinstalled on the system or I have to grab it with XCode? I'm new to Mac development, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visit [Apple's Xcode page](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Once you click "View Downloads" and *log in*, you should have access to previous versions of Xcode.

Comment: Hi, It requires registration and $99. Is it possible to get for free? Or maybe there is a link to download latest SDK without getting whole XCode stuff. All I need is simple SDK for desktop development not iOS. Thank you.

Comment: It is free to register as an apple developer: https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/

Comment: Well, I see there is XCode-3.2.6 for Snow Leopard and iOS SDK-4.3. Problem is I don't need iOS SDK as I mentioned above. Does it includes regular MAC SDK or iOS only? Thank you.

Comment: @Igor Your Snow Leopard DVD has Xcode. All versions of Xcode have the Mac OS X SDK, but the versions of Xcode that run on Snow Leopard don't have the 10.7 SDK. Since you're not interested in iOS development, you can just install Xcode from your Snow Leopard DVD.

Comment: @Igor are you worried about space or bandwidth? XCode runs at ~3GB and the version with IOS SDK is an extra ~250MB. Unless you are bound by either, I'd grab this version. This will do everything you need it to do in terms of mac (desktop) development (and more). And no, you don't need to download c/gcc/etc. XCode comes with compilers, etc.

Comment: @JP, neither. Problem is I am very very new to Mac development, but I have some experience with Linux. I just don't need something that will be unuseful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you pay the annual fee to Apple for [iOS Developer access](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/), you can [download Xcode 4.2 (and iOS SDK 5) for Snow Leopard directly from Apple](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard.dmg). Otherwise, you can either torrent it or, with [free registration](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/), download the older [Xcode 3.2.6 (and iOS SDK 4.3) for Snow Leopard directly from Apple](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg).

Source: http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

Comment: Can you upload an app made with XCode 4.2 to their crappy AppStore?

Comment: torrenting is NOT illegal, anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above suggestions worked as of July 2018, though the following link (developer access required) should do the trick for OS X 10.6.8 (using the v1.1 updater from Software Update): https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.2_developer_tools_beta_20728/xcode322_2148_developerdvd.dmg

Comment: "Xcode 3.2.2 Developer Tools" is the title on the download page - and it works great! Thanks.